# position absolute margin bottom

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, margin

Hi i have some problem with my plugin.
my plugin is a `jquery` dialog.
The problem is an `css` the position absolute popup margin bottom doesn't work.

this is my plugin [jquery.dialog](https://github.com/decoder10/jquery.dialog)

i have some script when the dialog height bigger  window height and to popup div i give som margin bottom but it doesn't work.

and screenshot

[image]

example in jsfiddle

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljke7/1/)

thanks for help

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If i am understanding it correctly hes trying to add a space to the bottom but its not working.

Comment: Can you point exactly where that code is and maybe quote it in the question source?

Comment: yes when the height of popup bigger then window height i add margin bottom to popup but it doesn't work

Comment: the source code is in github https://github.com/decoder10/jquery.dialog

Comment: You mean you want to achieve something shown in your screenshot (that extra space), but in reality there is no space between the `save` button and the bottom of the page?

Comment: yes but no space between the popup block and the bottom of the page, margin bottom are in popup block but doesn't work

Comment: Can you post a simple example on `jsfiddle` ?

Comment: example jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ljke7/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can do one more thing like 
decrease your image height or increase your div height

like this

```
 <img src="../images/one.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt=""/>
```

or

```
<div style="height:250px;">

      <img src="../images/one.jpg" alt=""/>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add these styles to the parent element, which is the container:

```
display: block;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-top: XXpx;
margin-top: -XXpx;
```

in this case, XX is the extra height in pixels.

Answer (score -1):

This type of issue is occur when you give the fixed height. so first of all you need to check which div have fixed height and you want to give height of current div you need to give after css code with **!important** keyword 
something like this

```
.className
 {
    width:150px!important;
 }
```

i hope it is work fine.

Comment: try to increase your div height i hope it works fine.